# Should FileOutputStream.close(); be called in catch block of IOException?

Tags: java, android

I just wondered if my object of `FileOutputStream`; `out.close();` should be called in the catch block? Because the out object is still "open" in case of something happends.

If not, should anything else with the `FileOutputStream` object be handled in the catch block?

```
  public void saveBitmap(){

    final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), folderName);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(myDir, getFileName() + getFileExtension());
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {

        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        viewToBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);

        }

        out.flush();
        out.getFD().sync();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        //should I out.close(); here too?

        e.printStackTrace();
        onBitmapSavedListener(false, null);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you should not be able to use `out` in `catch` because you declared it in `try`

Comment: @rala Just changed so its possible now

Answer (score 2):

You should close the connection in a finally block. So you can be sure it'll close on end of class.

Comment: But what if an error happends and we then go to the catch block? Should the connection be closed there too and be flushed?

Comment: Finally block will always be executed. This way if has occured an error or not the connection will be closed.